# X11 forwarding to IP doesn't work on some servers. I can't find any config differences

Tags: x11, aix, xterm, xming

This command allows me to send an xterm to xming on my windows desktop:

```
xterm -display 10.13.18.125:0 (my workstation IP)
```

For the servers that it doesn't work with the IP, It will work for some users to use localhost:10 as the display but if I su to oracle user for example, it doesn't work until I copy my .Xauthority entry to that user.

I'd like to set my display to an IP_address:0 and not mess with xauth. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Some basic information.
So you basically want to workaround the normal X forwarding and X authentication magic which should be setup by ssh/sshd automagically? If I understand your description correctly (you do not provide any error messages for the cases where it fails) then X forwarding works OK, but X authentication does not. I can only recommend you to read up on this, best documentation that explains it thoroughly is from the O'Reilly book "SSH, The Secure Shell: The Definitive Guide" which seems to be available via
http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch09_03.htm

Comment: You basically seem to want to disable X authentication on the X client (the server you connect to) to forward the display to your X server. Pay attention that then anybody might be able to send the display to their machine as you disabled X authentication. That would be the worst case, and maybe a little bit far-fetched but that's why I'd recommend to first read up on this ;)